# "Embedding" a folder into a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, embedding

I have a script library stored in `.../lib/` that I want to embed into my program. So far, that sounds simple: On Windows, I'd use Windows Resource Files - on MacOS, I'd put them into a `Resource` folder and use the proper API to access the current bundle and it's resources. On plain Linux, I am not too sure how to do it... But, I want to be cross-platform anyway.

Now, I know that there are tools like IncBin (https://github.com/graphitemaster/incbin) and alike, but they are best used for single files. What I have, however, might even require some kind of file system abstraction.

So here is the few guesses and estimates I did. I'd like to know if there is possibly a better solution - or others, in general.

- Create a Zip file and use MiniZ in order to read it's contents off a `char` array. Basically, running the zip file through IncBin and passing it as a buffer to MiniZ to let me work on that.
- Use an abstracted FS layer like PhysicsFS or TTVFS and add the possibility to work off a Zip file or any other kind of archive.

Are there other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: How about this? https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/

Comment: Do you need to be able to write to these files too?

Comment: Write a C program, which creates C sources from all the files in your directory (simple `const char file_1[] = { 0x01, 0x02. ...};`), then compile your program with these generated sources. This is the only portable way.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, and I solved it by locating the library relative to argv[0].  But that only works if you invoke the program by its absolute path -- i.e., not via $PATH in the shell.  So I invoke my program by a one-line script in ~/bin, or any other directory that's in your search path:

exec /wherever/bin/program "$@"

When the program is run, argv[0] is set to "/wherever/bin/program", and it knows to look in "/wherever/lib" for the related scripts.

Of course if you're installing directly into standard locations, you can rely on the standard directory structure, such as /usr/local/bin/program for the executable and /etc/program for related scripts & config files.  The technique above is just when you want to be able to install a whole bundle in an arbitrary place.

EDIT:  If you don't want the one-line shell script, you can also say:

alias program=/wherever/bin/program

Comment: Definitively a nice one, will give this a shot :) Didn't think about using `argv[0]` actually...

Comment: Also if your bundle is in your home directory, you can use "~" normally in the one-liner script, e.g.:

exec ~/mybundle/bin/program "$@"

As an alternative to all this, I once played with calling readlink on /proc/self/exe, but that's not very portable.  I resisted the extra one-line script at first, but grew to love it.